# Prevent click events from firing on elements behind a closing dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dialog that appears in front of other elements on the page. I want the user to be able to drag items from that dialog to the page, and I'm using pointer events to make it work on both desktop and mobile devices.

In the example below, I've only added a `"pointerdown"` event that hides the dialog. But in my real use case I'm handling dragging with `"pointermove"` and `"pointerup"` events as well.

This all works as expected until you try it out on a mobile device. Dragging works fine, but for some reason, mobile devices seem to fire the 'click' event on elements behind the dialog when tapping the green square. This results in the dialog opening back up again when tapping it.

How can I ignore the click event in this scenario?

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.style.display = "";
});

dialog.addEventListener("pointerdown", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  dialog.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
}

#dialog {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `"touchstart"` event listener and call `event.preventDefault()`. You can keep your pointer events do their thing as usual.

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.style.display = "";
});

dialog.addEventListener("pointerdown", e => {
  dialog.style.display = "none";
});

dialog.addEventListener("touchstart", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 20px;
}

#dialog {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;"></div>
```